# "element is not attached to the page document" Expection thrown after adding the implicit wait for selenium automation

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have added implicit wait in my code and it results in error "Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Below is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

service_obj = Service("C:/Users/divya/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_obj)

driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-keyword").send_keys("ber")
# time.sleep(2)

products = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='products']/div")
count = len(products)
assert count > 0

for product in products:
    product.find_element(By.XPATH, "div/button").click() #=======ERROR HERE=============

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".cart-icon").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='PROCEED TO CHECKOUT']").click()
# time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='text']").send_keys("rahulshettyacademy")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".promoBtn").click()
```

Sleep() functions work fine instead of implicit waits.

Anyone having suggestion/reason for the same. Please guide

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for some time after searching:

```
driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-keyword").send_keys("ber")
time.sleep(1)

products = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='products']/div")
count = len(products)
assert count > 0

i = 0
for i in range(len(products)):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='products']//button)[" + str(i + 1) + "]").click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".cart-icon").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='PROCEED TO CHECKOUT']").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='text']").send_keys("rahulshettyacademy")

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".promoBtn").click()
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for writing. I have the same concern. Sleep() works but why not waits?

Comment: implicitly wait is for page loading, some elements will take time to load even after the page loading completes, in that scenario, you can use explicit wait also instead of time.sleep().  We have to use time.sleep() in scenarios like - some webpages, the inner content will load after some time once the page load completes.  If this works for you marks this as the answer.